# SQL query for group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table values like below,

```
seqno,bill_no,bill_seq,first_name,last_name,phone_number,inserted date
1   11  1   KUTH    MUT1    96290   11-OCT-16
2   12  2   KUTH    MUT1    2   11-OCT-16
3   13  3   KUTH    MUT1    3   11-OCT-16
4   14  4   KUTH    MUT1    4   11-OCT-16
5   15  5   KUTH    MUT1    5   11-OCT-16
6   16  6   KUTH    MUT1    6   13-OCT-16
7   17  7   KUTH    MUT1    96290   13-OCT-16
8   18  8   KUTH    MUT1    8   13-OCT-16
9   19  9   KUTH    MUT1    9   13-OCT-16
10  20  10  KUTH    MUT1    96290   13-OCT-16
```

expected output:

1. based on phone number it should group
2. it should sort based on min seq_number and phone number group combination.
3. The old date rows always come first for example the seqno 1 is inserted on 11-oct but 7 and 10 are inserted on 13-oct but the result start from minimum seqno and old date for a group of phone and for a seqno 2 it should look for any new date row phone number is matching or not, if not matching then sequence 2.. it will continue for other rows as well.

```
1   11  1   KUTH    MUT1    96290   11-OCT-16
7   17  7   KUTH    MUT1    96290   13-OCT-16
10  20  10  KUTH    MUT1    96290   13-OCT-16
2   12  2   KUTH    MUT1    2   11-OCT-16
3   13  3   KUTH    MUT1    3   11-OCT-16
4   14  4   KUTH    MUT1    4   11-OCT-16
5   15  5   KUTH    MUT1    5   11-OCT-16
6   16  6   KUTH    MUT1    6   13-OCT-16
8   18  8   KUTH    MUT1    8   13-OCT-16
9   19  9   KUTH    MUT1    9   13-OCT-16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT seqno,bill_no,bill_seq,first_name,last_name,phone_number,inserted date
FROM (
  SELECT seqno,bill_no,bill_seq,first_name,last_name,phone_number,inserted date
    , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY phone_number ORDER BY seqno) AS rank
  FROM table)
ORDER BY phone_number,rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not quite clear if you are looking for 2 queries or 1, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select 
    seqno, bill_no, bill_seq, first_name, last_name, phone_number, inserted date 
from 
    table
group by
    phone_number, seqno, bill_no, bill_seq, first_name, last_name, inserted date
order by 
    phone_number, seqno asc
```

Comment: I am expecting single query. Actually the data insert every day with new sequence number. The idea here is, need to get first row inserted some old date with a phone number and if the new date row has the same row then it should come next to old date row.

Comment: I think that the proposed query does this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to order first all row by minimum value of seq_number on each phone number group and afterwards by inserted_date within each group?

Then i guess this will do it:

SELECT seqno,bill_no,bill_seq,first_name,last_name,phone_number,inserted_date
FROM (
  SELECT seqno,bill_no,bill_seq,first_name,last_name,phone_number,inserted_date
    , MIN (seqno) OVER (PARTITION BY phone_number) AS minimum
  FROM table1) X
ORDER BY minimum,inserted_date